# Why is finding the maximum cut NP-hard?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I recently found that finding the maximum cut in a graph with weighted edges is NP-hard. However, finding the minimum cut is not NP-hard.
If I would inverse the weights on all edges and then search for the minimum cut, wouldn't that give me the maximum cut on the original graph? And if not, why?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume by inverse you mean changing a weight w to -w.

In this case, the min-cut of the adjusted graph does indeed solve the max-cut problem for the original graph.

Unfortunately, efficient algorithms for solving the min-cut problem are only known when all the weights are non-negative, which means we can only solve max-cut efficiently if all the weights are non-positive.

Comment: You are right, I think OP meant "opposite". I've updated my answer with a proof for the opposite case, but this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: What if you create a graph with `w(i) = MAX(weights) -w(i)` and run min cut max flow? All the weights are positives and the min cut in the new graph would be the max cut. Isn't it?

Comment: this will introduce a bias towards using fewer edges so is not eaxctly the same

Answer (score 6):

The max cut of a graph is not the min cut of a graph with inverse weights. Consider the graphs below: red line is min cut and green max cut.[image]

If by inverse you meant "opposite" then indeed finding a maximum for one comes down to finding a minimum cut for the other. The proof is straightforward.

Let G be any graph, and G' the graph with opposite weights. Let `v_1,..., v_n` be the sequence of vertices to remove to make the maximum cut of G, and `w_1,..., w_n` the associated weights. `M = w_1 + ... + w_n = max(cuts)`. Obviously `v_1,..., v_n` is a cut in G'. Let `v'_1,...,v'_m` be any cut in G' and `w'_1,..., w'_n` their weights in G'.

Then `v'_1,...,v'_m` is also a cut in G with weight `-(w'_1+...+w'_q)`. By definition of M, we have `-(w'_1+...+w'_q) <= M` and so `w'_1+...+w'_q >= -M`. So we have that -M is the min cut value in G' and `v_1,..., v_n` realizes this value, it is the min cut of G'.

As to why it is not an easy problem to solve, see 
Peter de Rivaz's answer.

Comment: To complement the answer, the mentioned 'inversion of weights' is particularly spectacular if all edge weights are `1`, where the instance stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

To find the class of a problem (Polynomial or Non-Polynomial), you should use [Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)) which is a mechanism to transform a problem into another problem. You can find more discussion in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/is-logical-min-cut-np-complete.